# A connection attempt failed -- Smtp.Send in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email

I have being trying to send message for quite a while now. But the Stmp.send is failing and giving an error .

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond 202.71.99.194:25

```
 System.Net.Mail.MailMessage m = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(
                             new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("email@yahoo.com", "Web Registration"),
                             new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(user.Email));
                    m.Subject = "Email confirmation";
                    m.Body = string.Format("Dear {0}<BR/>Thank you for your registration, please click on the below link to comlete your registration: <a href=\"{1}\" title=\"User Email Confirm\">{1}</a>", user.Username, Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { Token = user.Id, Email = user.Email }, Request.Url.Scheme));
                    m.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.google.com");
                    smtp.Port = 587;
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email@gmail.com", password);

                    smtp.Send(m);
```

I disabled my antivirus and tried yet all failed. Please where did i go wrong ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems your mail server has time out issue. Have you tried again?

Comment: Try changin the port number or use a different smtp server like outlook

Comment: Try to Telnet to your mail server using those credentials to make sure there are no connection issues.

Comment: @Tommassiov havent hosted yet. I am running on IIS , VS. Or do i have to host first perhaps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Port / firewall / AntiVirus ,also change secure [apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) setting .

Comment: Its working after the change apps setting. I repsumed thats what worked for me. thanks